# NSDictionary turns into NSCFString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm encountering a weird issue where storing an `NSDictionary` to the `NSUserDefaults` and then retrieving it converts it to an `NSCFString`.

Here's where I save the data:

```
- (void)saveProgress
{
    // Save our progress to the user defaults.
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *progressDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"session_progress"] != nil) {
        [progressDict addEntriesFromDictionary:[defaults dictionaryForKey:@"session_progress"]];
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *targetsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if ([progressDict objectForKey:@"targets"] != nil) {
        [targetsDict addEntriesFromDictionary:[progressDict objectForKey:@"targets"]];
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *trackableDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if ([targetsDict objectForKey:@"mda_sao_ext_04"]) {
        [trackableDict addEntriesFromDictionary:[targetsDict objectForKey:@"mda_sao_ext_04"]];
    }
    [trackableDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                      forKey:@"viewed"];
    NSLog(@"SAVE Trackable %@ %@", [trackableDict class], trackableDict);
    [targetsDict setObject:trackableDict
                    forKey:@"mda_sao_ext_04"];
    NSLog(@"SAVE Targets %@ %@", [targetsDict class], targetsDict);
    [progressDict setObject:targetsDict
                     forKey:@"targets"];
    [defaults setObject:progressDict
                 forKey:@"session_progress"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

And here's where I load the data:

```
- (NSInteger)loadProgress
{
    // Load our progress from the user defaults.
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"session_progress"] == nil) {
        return 0;
    }
    NSDictionary *progressDict = [defaults dictionaryForKey:@"session_progress"];
    if ([progressDict objectForKey:@"targets"] == nil) {
        return 0;
    }
    NSDictionary *targetsDict = [progressDict objectForKey:@"targets"];
    NSLog(@"LOAD Targets %@ %@", [targetsDict class], targetsDict);
    NSInteger viewedCount = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *trackableDict in targetsDict) {
        NSLog(@"LOAD Trackable %@ %@", [trackableDict class], trackableDict);
        if ([[trackableDict objectForKey:@"viewed"] boolValue]) {
            ++viewedCount;
        }
    }

    return viewedCount;
}
```

The app crashes in `loadProgress`. Here's the output to the console:

```
LOAD Targets __NSCFDictionary {
    "mda_sao_ext_04" =     {
        scanned = 1;
        viewed = 1;
    };
} 
LOAD Trackable __NSCFString mda_sao_ext_04
```

You can see from the first trace that `mda_sao_ext_04 is a dictionary, but for some reason it gets converted to a string.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You probably failed to sufficiently `retain` (or `strong`) your dictionary and it went bye-bye somewhere along the way.

Comment: Though note that in one case you're printing "targetsDict" and in the other "trackableDict" -- haven't parsed it deep enough to see where trackableDict might originate.

Comment: Ah, yes.  You're just using the wrong mechanism to iterate through a dictionary.  As the two answers indicate.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Generally, yes, but it's also the sort of mistake one can make when simply not paying enough attention.  Admit it -- you've done things as stupid, only you knew how to debug them rather than having to make your ignorance public here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fast enumeration of NSDictionary returns keys, not values.

`for (NSDictionary *trackableDict in targetsDict) {`

here you loop over all keys. Change

```
NSLog(@"LOAD Trackable %@ %@", [trackableDict class], trackableDict);
```

to

```
NSLog(@"LOAD Trackable %@ %@", [trackableDict class], targetsDict[trackableDict]);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (NSDictionary *trackableDict in targetsDict)
```

this `for` construction iterates through keys, not values. So, to get value you have to either

```
for (NSDictionary *trackableDict in [targetsDict allValues])
```

or

```
for (NSString *trackableKey in targetsDict)
{
    NSDictionary *trackableDict = targetsDict[trackableKey];
    .....
}
```